# Getting error from login to master details page in xamarin.forms in view model?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation, master-detail

When i trying to navigate from login page to masterDetailpage, I am getting error says
 "**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**"

I tried this in the login function when user successful logged in

```
async void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
            if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                if (IsValidated)
                {
                    await navigationRef.PushPopupAsync(new LoaderPage()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    userDetails = await webServicesRepository.UserLogin(Phone, Password, "123113123", "Android").ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (userDetails != null && userDetails.status == "200")
                    {                           

                        await navigationRef.PopPopupAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        MasterDetailPage fpm = new MasterDetailPage
                        {
                            Master = new MainMenuPageMaster(),
                            Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
                        };
                        Application.Current.MainPage = fpm;
                        //Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainMenuPage());
                        //await navigationRef.PushAsync(new MainMenuPage()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await navigationRef.PopPopupAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Constants.DISPLAY_POPUP_TITLE, Constants.NO_DATA_FOUND, Constants.DISPLAY_POPUP_BUTTON).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Constants.DISPLAY_POPUP_TITLE, "You must fill all areas correctly!", Constants.DISPLAY_POPUP_BUTTON).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Constants.DISPLAY_NETWORK_ERROR_TITLE, Constants.DISPLAY_NETWORK_ERROR_MESSAGE, Constants.DISPLAY_POPUP_BUTTON).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

        } 
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Constants.DISPLAY_POPUP_TITLE, Constants.NO_DATA_FOUND, Constants.DISPLAY_POPUP_BUTTON).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

MasterDetailPage :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="intSetSet.MainMenuPage"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:XXXXXX"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MainMenuPageMaster x:Name="masterPage" Title="Menu" Icon="ListIcon.png" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:HomePage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

c#

```
public partial class MainMenuPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainMenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {                
                masterPage.MenuItemsListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<EventArgs>(this, "OpenMenu", args =>
                {
                    IsPresented = !IsPresented;
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }            
        }

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MainMenuPageModel;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
            //var page = item.TargetType;
            page.Title = item.Title;

            Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
            IsPresented = false;

            masterPage.MenuItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```

ContentPage to generate List options:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XXXXX.MainMenuPageMaster"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  x:FieldModifier="public"
                  HasUnevenRows="true"                  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#CEDAEE">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="20">
                        <Image Margin="10,10,0,0"
                               Source="setsetlogo.png"
                               WidthRequest="80"
                               HeightRequest="80"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Text="IntSetSet"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontSize="24" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView  BackgroundColor="Teal"
                              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                              HeightRequest="1"></BoxView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     BackgroundColor="#CEDAEE">
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10"
                                         Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                                       WidthRequest="40"
                                       HeightRequest="40"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
                                <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       FontSize="Medium" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView  BackgroundColor="Teal"
                                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      HeightRequest="1"></BoxView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#CEDAEE" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" Text="LogOut" BackgroundColor="#CEDAEE" TextColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                    </Button>
                    <!--<Button Clicked="LogoutButton_Clicked" Text="LogOut" BackgroundColor="#CEDAEE" TextColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                    </Button>-->
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainMenuPageMaster : ContentPage
    {

        public MainMenuPageMaster()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new MainMenuPageViewModel();
        }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class MainMenuPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MainMenuPageModel> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public ICommand LogoutCommand { get; }
        public MainMenuPageViewModel()
        {
            try
            {
                MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MainMenuPageModel>(new[]
                {
                    new MainMenuPageModel { Id = 0, Title = "Home", Icon="shop.png", TargetType= typeof(HomePage) },
                    new MainMenuPageModel { Id = 1, Title = "Profile", Icon="shop.png", TargetType= typeof(ProfilePage) },
                    new MainMenuPageModel { Id = 2, Title = "Referral History", Icon="paper_money.png", TargetType= typeof(ReferralHistoryPage) },


                });


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I want to Navigate from the login page to master details page on successful login

Comment: you need to look at the InnerException for more detail about what the root problem is

Comment: @jason  it would be great if you will share some reference

Comment: The Exception object has an InnerException property.  For TargetInvocationException the InnerException usually has more information about the root cause of the exception.

Comment: When i tried Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
I am getting this : Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-16,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-25 17:32:37.952 I/mono-stdout( 3397): Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-16,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: @jason I have updated my question little bit so you can get a clear idea about the issue. Also, printing inner exception in login function catch block.

Comment: use the debugger to view the InnerException and stack trace instead, or google how to fix the looper problem

Comment: Check the CLR exception in your Visual studio debugguer exception if not already. Quite sur the prob is around here : 

     var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
            //var page = item.TargetType;
            page.Title = item.Title;

            Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
            IsPresented = false;

            masterPage.MenuItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;